# Use of automated assessment of programming assignments

Tags: education, tools, code, homework

*(This is a reworking of [Software for submitting and testing programming assignments](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/20226/13852).)*

First, a bit of background. Many courses in applied mathematics have a programming component, where students are asked to implement algorithms (say, in Matlab) and possibly test them using a given set of interesting data. Although they are a valuable part of the education, these usually receive little love from the students (who, moreover, have rarely received a rigorous  training in programming). The result is -- with rare exceptions -- lazy hacks at best and "at least it looks like code" (often followed by my favorite, "it worked on my machine") at worst.

So I am thinking about having students submit their programming assignments via an automated assessment software. The idea is to give them instant feedback on their (repeated) submission with the goal of

1. saving the TAs from having to check every submission and (if they are generous) inserting all the missing semicola to make the code run, and
2. trying to increase the student's motivation to do more than the bare minimum by introducing some gamification elements (giving points for the fastest/most accurate code, for example, or a current ranking to encourage resubmitting improved solutions).

Hence my question (which is hopefully relevant to other disciplines as well): Has anybody tried such a thing? Did it actually lead to less work and/or more student involvement? Any hints on what to do, and what to avoid?

(I know there is the [VPL](http://vpl.dis.ulpgc.es/) module for Moodle, and we have an [in-house system](http://www.s3.uni-duisburg-essen.de/research/jack.html) that can provide the necessary functionality, so I'm not asking for software recommendations here. That said, if some software provides a specific feature you've used successfully, by all means mention it -- bonus points if it's open source.)

Comment: Using a testing/measuring system to pre-screen the submissions, and to help score them, may make sense. But the TAs still DO have to check every final submission to make sure it actually solves the stated problem in a reasonable way, rather than only solving enough of the problem to pass the test or doing so in some excessively fragile manner.

Comment: @keshlam True, but if that can easily happen your testing framework is not good enough.

Comment: Testing frameworks, in general, are not good enough. Since testing the complete problem space is usually not practical, they're statistical bets on common failure modes... and if you overlook a failure, you're doing the student a disservice by letting their code pass. Moreover, you should be grading partly on code _quality_ -- clarity, appropriateness, etc. -- and no machine scoring system yet invented does a good job with that, despite many decades of attempts.

Comment: @keshlam - to be clear, I wasn't planning on using the system for *grading* submissions; the assignments would be either pass/fail, or the system would serve as a gatekeeper to make sure the submissions to be graded met a certain minimum standard of correctness.

Comment: OK, in that mode it's more of an "automated TA's assistant". Makes sense. And extra points for extra work on performance, or on handling some additional set of cases, is a nice idea -- though I'm biased; I typically scored pretty high in those competitions.

Comment: You mean something similar to [codingame](http://www.codingame.com/)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**TL;DR**

We did something along this lines for Java-based programming assignments. Students and TAs generally like it. It was **a lot** of work for us.

**(Very) Long Version**

I used to teach software engineering at a large public university in Austria. We implemented a similar approach for two courses back there, for a **400+ students bachelor-level** distributed systems course, and **for a 150 students master-level** course on middleware and enterprise application engineering. Both courses included large, time-consuming Java-based programming assignments, which students needed to solve individually three times per semester.

Traditionally, students would submit their solutions for both courses as [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) projects via our university-wide Moodle system. After the deadline, TAs would download and execute the submissions, and grade manually based on extensive check lists that we provided. There was usually a bit of huffing and puffing among students about this grading. Sometimes, TAs would not understand correct solutions (after looking at dozens of similar programs, your mind tends to get sloppy). Sometimes, different TAs would grade similar programs differently (the sheer size required some parallelization of grading and the tasks were complex, hence it was impossible to do check lists that covered all possible cases). Sometimes, the assignments were actually under-specified or unclear, and students lost points for simple misunderstandings. Sometimes, applications that actually worked on the student's machine failed on the TA's machine. Generally, it was hard for students to estimate in advance how many points their submissions would be worth. Given that those two courses are amongst the most difficult / most time-consuming courses in the entire SE curriculum, this was all but optimal.

Hence, we decided to move to a **more automated solution**. Basically, we codified our various check lists into a set of hundreds of [JUnit](http://junit.org) test cases, which we gave to our students in source code. Additionally, we kept back a smaller set of tests, which were similar but used different test data. The tests would also serve as reference implementation - if the assignment text did not specify how e.g., a given component should behave in a given borderline case, what the tests expected was the expected behavior. Our promise to the students was that, if all the tests for a given task pass, and the student did not *game* our test system (more on this below), not much can go wrong anymore with the grading (it was possible to get minor point losses anyway for things impossible to test automatically, but those things could not amount for more than a small percentage of all points).

**EDIT after comments**
Note that I was saying *more automated*, not *fully automated*. Human TAs still look at the code. There is no *grading Web service* or something like that (this usually does not work, as keshlam correctly notes). On a high level, what we did is that we provided the requirements for students not only in written text anymore, but also in form of formal executable unit tests. The new process is roughly like that:

1. TA downloads submission from Moodle and starts tests (takes about 10 minutes).
2. While tests are running, TA browses over the code, does some spot checking of code, and checks a few things not covered by the tests.
3. When the tests are done, the TA notes down the results of the tests and his own observations.
4. If something severe happens (e.g., compile error), the TA sighs, takes a deep breath, and falls back to manually grading (and, likely, complaining a bit in our mailing list).

**Advantages:**

- Students now have a good feeling about **how many points** they will get in the end. No nasty surprises anymore.
- The TA **effort for grading** is now much, much lower, maybe 1/3 of the previous time. Hence, they have more time to look at problematic solutions and help students actually produce assignments.
- The tests, good or bad (more on this later), are **the same for everybody**. Lenient and strict TAs are much less of a problem.
- Working solutions now **work** no matter if the grading TA understands the solution or not.
- Students get **rapid feedback** on the quality of their solution, but not *so* rapid that it makes sense to just program against the tests without thinking. One good side effect of the way we built our tests is that simply executing the tests for many tasks takes  10+ minutes (starting an application server, deploying code, ...). Students need to think before starting tests, just like they would if they would test against, e.g., a real staging server.
- Students do not need to waste time writing test applications / test data. Before, one problem that made the student effort in these courses skyrocket was that students did not only have to program the assignments themselves, but also needed to write various demo programs / test data sets to test and showcase their solutions. This has become entirely obsolete with the automated test framework, significantly reducing the amount of **boilerplate code** that students need to write. In the end, we can now focus more on the actual content of the labs, and not on writing stupid test code.
- All in all, our personal impression as well as student evaluations have shown that the majority of students **appreciates** the automated test system.

**Problems:**

- The **initial effort** for us was certainly non-trivial. Coming up with the first version of the tests required a concerted effort of 6 or more TAs and 2 junior faculty over multiple months during the summer (not full-time of course, but still). Note that this was even though we utilize a widely used, standard testing framework - the effort was just in codifying our grading rules, finding and defining all corner cases, and writing everything down in useful tests. Further, as the assignments are complex distributed systems, so were the tests - we had to start application servers in-memory, hot-deploy and undeploy code, and make sure that all of this works out of the box on all major OS versions. All in all, writing the tests was an actual project, that required a lot of leadership and time commitment.
- While, overall, our total time spent arguing about grading has decreased, it is not zero. Most importantly, as students can now see the grading guidelines clearly written down in source code, they seem to feel more compelled to question requirements and grading decisions than before. Hence, we now get a lot of *But why should I do it like that? Doing it in X-Y-Other-Way would be much better!* questions and complaints (incidentally, in practically all cases, the "much better" way is also much less work / much easier for the student).
- While we were able to cover most of our original assignments, some things are **impossible to cover** in tests. In these cases, TAs still need to grade manually. In addition, in order to make our test framework technically work, students are now a bit more restricted in how they can solve the assignments than before.
- Some students feel compelled to try to **game** our grading system. They spend significant efforts into finding solutions that do not actually solve the assignments but still get full points. In general, these efforts fail (as we actually have pretty sophisticated backend tests that do not only check whether the behavior is correct on interface level, but also look "under the hood"). Occasionally, they succeed, leading us to improve our tests.
- Initially, we received some flack from a few students for a small number of **bugs in our tests**. The bugs were easy to fix and mostly not particularly severe, and most students understand that if you roll out a couple thousand lines of Java code for the first time, bugs will happen. However, some will take the opportunity to complain. A lot.
- We had the impression that the number of copied solutions **(plagiarism) was up** the first time we rolled out the automated tests. Note that we had automated plagiarism checks long before, and nothing had changed in this regard, but apparently students assumed that cheating would go unnoticed with the automated testing.

Comment: Thank you for this in-depth answer! (I was certainly not planning anything on that scale, but then, I'm not a software engineer :) It was my feeling, too, that the success of such a project depends on the quality of the tests, but also that preparing such tests would improve the quality of the assignments themselves. Would you say that a significant portion of the benefit came from having a framework (including boilerplate code to make it easier for the students), even without automated testing?

Comment: Also, I found your remark about increased plagiarism interesting. I was not planning on including that in the framework, but it seems that it might be a good idea.

Comment: @ChristianClason I am not sure if I follow. In our case, the framework and the automated testing were basically the same thing. On a high level, what we did is that we provided the requirements for students not only in written text anymore, but also in form of formal executable unit tests. We did not have a special submission server or somesuch. Students still submitted via Moodle. After the deadline, TAs still ran the code against the tests and noted down the results.

Comment: Thanks, that exactly answered my question (and means I misunderstood initially).

Answer (score 7):

**TLDR**

We used fully automated testing for programming assignments in a second-year course. We directly showed students their grade and allowed them to re-submit as often as they liked. Students loved it, and it freed up time for the TAs to hold far more office hours.

**Long version**

We developed our own in-house solution for a second-year Data Structures course. The exercises came with compiling skeleton code and interfaces for the test software to hook into. Students would submit to a web server running a Perl script, which would then compile the code alongside the testing framework, run a number of tests and display the grade. We did not provide the students with the tests, but did display the outcome of each test, usually in a way that made clear where the problem was, without revealing the exact test data. In addition, students were allowed to submit as many times as they liked. We explicitly encouraged them to submit early and often.

Advantages:

- It allowed us to **harshly punish code that doesn't work**, or gives compile errors (we gave 0 marks for both).
- **Complete uniformity in grading**. Fully automating the grading meant that solutions that implemented the same functionality would always get the same mark.
- By being very clear about the requirements, and at the same time being fair by allowing them to re-submit, we significantly **reduced complaints about grading**.
- We had one TA (myself) who was mainly responsible for developing tests, and one who maintained the submission server. This freed up the other TAs to **hold many more office hours**. We had TAs available 4 hours per day, every day of the week.
- **Students can correct (and learn from!) their mistakes** before the grade is final. The good students in particular did not rest before they had a perfect grade.

Disadvantages:

- **Can promote plagiarism**. We did not bother with any plagiarism checks, but this could become a significant problem, especially if assignments are reused from previous years.
- **Non-functional requirements are hard to test**. While it is possible to test certain coding style requirements automatically, this is much harder than having a TA look it over. It is also much easier to game these automatic tests.
- **Can promote 'coding against the tests'**. Some students did not bother to implement even the most basic correctness tests themself, instead relying purely on the server. For the next iteration of the course, we are considering basing part of the mark on whether student-written tests can succesfully detect our incorrect solutions. This will hopefully force them to think about testing their code as well.
- **Can shift focus from high-level understanding of the material to implementation details**. Automated testing relies on the students being able to produce valid code. If the students are struggling with syntax, it can get in the way of higher-level objectives like the algorithms and data structures involved.

Conclusions:

Overall, both the students and the professor and TAs really appreciated this form of grading. The students received instant, unambiguous feedback about their work and the chance to learn from their mistakes while it still counted. At the same time, it allowed the majority of TAs to focus on helping the students understand the material, instead of tedious evaluation.

The Java testing framework is available on [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/Mangara/checker). Unfortunately, it lacks documentation.

Comment: Thanks; I especially liked the idea of "inverse problems" where the students write tests against provided implementations.

Comment: And I wish I could make good of my promise of bonus points for your open source framework.

Comment: Turns out I can :)

Answer (score 1):

We used CourseMarker in combination with BlueJ for teaching first year students Java. There are three main criteria for marking: typographic correctness (layout, indentation, comments, etc.), semantic correctness (does the program run and do what it is supposed to do), and programming language features (whether specified programming constructs are present in the code). It is possible to supply a supporting code (a skeleton of the program, where students fill the gaps) or let the students start from scratch.

The CourseMarker administrator (in our case the module leader) can set up a marking scheme as a combination of the three main criteria and their sub-criteria. It is possible to configure CourseMarker to accept multiple submissions. Students can submit initial version of their program, receive immediate feedback, make necessary corrections and submit again. The feedback for the students can pinpoint the exact problem and its location, and provide suggestions for improvement. The feedback for the lecturers is statistical data about students’ performance.

We set optional training tasks for the student to self-study (no limit over the number of submissions) and a coursework, which was assessed (3 to 5 submissions for each part depending on its complexity).

There are also embedded methods for plagiarism detection, which compare student’s work for similarity. The comparison is not just semantic, it accounts for changes in the code that actually do not change the logic of the program. The suspect students’ work is reported to the lecturers.

The exam (also on CourseMarker) combined multiple choice questions, fill-in-the-blanks questions, and constructing flow charts and programming code. All the students answer the same set of questions but they are ordered in random manner for each student. The order of the answers for multiple choice questions and the layout of elements for constructing flow charts or programming code are randomised, too.

Benefits - instant feedback to the students, especially useful for unsupervised work (remember the students are beginners in programming). Actually most of the students installed the client package on their computers at home and correspond with the university server via Internet. From lecturers’ point of view, it saves vast amount of time - we didn’t have to check and mark students’ work.

The main drawback of CourseMarker is its rigidity. Normally a programmer can write a piece of code in various ways. CourseMarker can be set to understand and assess only a pre-determined pattern, which should be specified in the task description. Any deviations from the pattern would trigger reducing the marks. So I made a point to explain that there are certain limitations working in this particular programming environment but in other circumstances, there are other options to be considered.

Comment: CourseMarker seems to be dead-ish by now - or was it never public?

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an answer to the question as posed but a few remarks I think you should consider before choosing an automatic mode of submission/grading.

I often give my students some assignments where programming is needed too (in the linear algebra course I taught I asked them to break Hill's cypher with the clue that certain words were somewhere in the medium length text and to create a drive (flight for extra points) simulation view in the classical perspective) though I assign such things for extra credit more often than as a part of regular homework.

My approach is that I restrict neither the choice of programming language, nor the operating system (I can program in 3 languages myself, but if you ask me to do it in some other one with substantially different syntax (like, say, Haskell), I will probably manage finally but I will just hate it). Also my solution to the "worked on my computer" problem is "bring your laptop and show me". If it, indeed, works, I have no objection.

I never ask anyone to do programming quickly (we all know that no program works as intended on the first run and that even if you know perfectly what you are doing, the debugging time exceeds the typing time) so I have no "do it in class" programming assignments. The way I make sure that the students get a quick feedback is just by assigning the tasks where, once you run your program, you see yourself whether it works or not. In some cases, like code breaking, it is apparent that if you get a meaningful text, then your approach and code make sense (I never ask for more than that because otherwise we should leave the students alone and start with shutting down all major software companies for their "sloppy code"). If it is crunching data, I supply a test sample, an answer to the test sample, and a real sample, so you, again can see everything once your code runs.

The thing I do when the assignment is submitted (full protocol, with most students whose abilities I know, I cut it down quite a lot) is to ask the student to run the code, to check the results, and to ask a few questions about the code itself afterwards. I always do an "oral examination" in this case because it is quicker and way more efficient in the sense that it allows me to correct minor stupid errors on the fly if the student knows what he's doing and just kill the students who do not with a couple of appropriately posed questions. The idea to try to read somebody else's code submitted in writing or to run and debug it myself has never even crossed my mind.

All submissions should be done during my office hours, not during the class time. I dislike the American way of assigning 20 problems of the same type each day and usually do 2-10 (depending on the course) each of which can be solved only if you combine several ideas in one program (of course, I explain which ones and how before the assignment). Such assignments are easy to check (either the code works, or it doesn't + either the student knows why that loop is there, or he doesn't) but not so easy to carry out. As to copying, as someone noted long time ago, "one's code is more individual than his fingerprints", and if you can copy a code changing its structure substantially, I just take it on faith that you can do it yourself as well if needed and don't really care.

Comment: good approach!.. but how many students do you have? not sure your approach works for 100 students class.

Answer (score -1):

I've taught programming courses (Java, C and C++) with large numbers of students (>100) for the last decade or so.  We have come up with a system that works well for us, which doesn't currently automate the marking (although we can add that), but does reduce the time spent marking and reduces disagreements.  Basically it reformats the source code (using LaTeX) and presents the files in the order most convenient for marking, but it also compiles and runs the program, and add the compiler messages and output to the .pdf file that the student actually submits.  This gives the student a specific environment the program has to work on (no more "well it works on my computer/compiler" etc) and the student gets to see the program output on which they will be marked.  If you design the requirements well enough, checking the correctness of the output visually is usually straightforward.  If you are interested in using it, Mrs Marsupial (who implemented it) makes it available from [GitHub](https://github.com/nlct/pass).

The real problem with automated marking is that they are not (currently) very good at assessing how maintainable the code is (e.g. how well written it is), just assessing "technical quality" - does it work? - is it efficient?  We need to discourage students from fixating on "well it works"

[image]

They need to start from the outset looking to write good quality code that is readable by humans as well as the compiler, and so far all of the automated marking systems I have seen so far have not been very good at that.  I have been planning to add some technical quality checks to our PASS system, but at the moment I still need to mark and give feedback on code quality and that is the time consuming bit.

Comment: @downvoter, some feedback on the reasons for the downvote would be appreciated.